# SQL server - Msg 213 - Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server, I am trying to insert values from one table to another by using the below query :

```
delete from tblTable1

insert into tblTable1 select * from tblTable1_Link
```

I am getting the following error :

> Column name or number of supplied
>   values does not match table
>   definition.

I am sure that both table having same structure, column names and same data type.

Thank you for your help. I have tried posting this to [sqlsvrtip](http://sqlsvrtip.com/) but I got no response so I though I would try here are there seems to be way more activity.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3):

Is one of the columns an IDENTITY column?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblTable1 ON
insert into tblTable1 select * from tblTable1_Link
SET IDENTITY_INSERT tblTable1 OFF
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please run this statement in your database and give us the output??

```
SELECT 
    c.name,
    c.is_identity,
    c.is_computed, 
    t.name 'Type name'
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE object_id = object_ID('tblTable1')
```

Questions:

- is there any column that has `is_identity` set to 1 (true) ?
- is there any column that has `is_computed` set to 1 (true) ?
- is there any column with a type of `timestamp` or `rowversion` ??

If you have any of those columns: you cannot easily set any of these in an `INSERT` statement. You can set the identity columns with some extra work, but computed columns or columns of type `TIMESTAMP` / `ROWVERSION` **cannot** be set under any circumstances.

That's why I'd recommend to **always** explicitly specify the list of columns - even if you need all of them:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tblTable1(col1, col2, ...., colX)
   SELECT col1, col2, ...., colX FROM dbo.tblTable1_Link
```

With this approach, you can leave out any columns that cannot be inserted quite easily...

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @Fosco as that's most likely the answer.

One note though, if you're simply caching a linked table and thus emptying it each time then you could just do something like:

```
DROP TABLE tblTable1 -- assuming there are no FKs

select * INTO tblTable1 from tblTable1_Link
--  Then Re-create keys / indexes
```

This will mean that if the schema of tblTable1_Link changes then that change will also be in the destination table.